# Graphic Design Resource for Indie Game Dev?

Tags: graphics-design

I'm creating my first game and want to improve upon the graphic design aspects of my game.

By graphic design I mean layout, font, spacing, etc..

Is there a good resource for learning graphic design for a programmer?

I've taken human-computer interaction classes, but that has more to do with task and making task as easy as possible for the user. Not necessarily about layout/spacing.

I mention layout/spacing twice because that's the biggest problem I'm having. I can clearly tell that things need to be spaced properly to be more visually pleasing.

Thanks to all that reply

Comment: Not really, I'm talking more about graphic design in the since of web page graphic design but the same concepts that  apply to games. Every comment in that link had to do with "how to create 2d art" or "how to do pixel art", etc...

Comment: That's the same question. It may not be the answers you want. The question asked there is **"Are there any good resources for learning game oriented graphic design?"** and those are the answers they got. Sorry that's not more helpful, but I think when talking to game developers those are the answers you get. You may want to ask this question on the [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: Joey, you can also place a bounty on the duplicate question, asking for better answers.

Comment: The topic you have in mind is probably game UI design.